# Mysql: Multiple updates from a single select

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, bigdata

I have a case where I need to match a group of fields as Unique on **Addresses** table, but for that, on database, i have to detect duplicates, delete them from database and update all associated foreign keys.

I could end up by making multiple queries:

- 1st for retrieving **original**.**id** and respective **duplicated**.**id**s;
- 2nd, 3rd and 4rd to set the associated tables foreign key to **original**.**id** where they have **duplicated**.**id**;
- 3rd for delete duplicated for database (or just mark some attribute as deleted to delete them on a 2nd query)

But the problem of multiple queries that send out information to a process is that it is an issue on big data.

For that i have to:

- Add a field to mark as deleted on **Addresses** table
- Run a single query that handles everything
- If we can't merge the **DELETE** statement on main query, we must delete all the deleted marked rows
- Remove the deleted field.

As long as i have taken on query tests, i came up with this idea:

```
SELECT `` FROM `Addresses` AS `Original`

WHERE
    ( UPDATE `A` SET `address_id` = `Original`.`id` WHERE `address_id` = `Duplicated`.`id` ) OR
    ( UPDATE `B` SET `address_id` = `Original`.`id` WHERE `address_id` = `Duplicated`.`id` ) OR
    ( UPDATE `C` SET `address_id` = `Original`.`id` WHERE `address_id` = `Duplicated`.`id` ) OR
    ( UPDATE `Addresses` SET `deleted` = true WHERE `id` = `Duplicated`.`id` )

INNER JOIN `Addresses` AS `Duplicated`
    ON
    `Original`.`id` < `Duplicated`.`id` AND
    `Original`.`street_id` = `Duplicated`.`street_id` AND
    `Original`.`city_id` = `Duplicated`.`city_id` AND
    `Original`.`door_number` = `Duplicated`.`door_number` AND
    `Original`.`floor` = `Duplicated`.`floor` AND
    `Original`.`extra` = `Duplicated`.`extra`
```

Comment: This is not possible in MySQL. You need to run multiple `UPDATE` statements

Comment: But if so, how do i share data from the SELECT with multiple updates?

Comment: You can't (not in MySQL) you need to repeat the `SELECT` statements as well. You could put the result of the `SELECT` into a temp table though and use that to select the rows to be updated.

Comment: What is temp table? Sorry, I had never use that. Could you specify as answer please?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I'm interested in this too!!